# Joining two tables having multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to join two tables, *Emphours* and *EmpStatus* to get each employee's hours  worked each day and in which status.

I tried to simulate the situation.
I need result similar to table 3.

Hours can also be grouped per week.

All I need Is Each employee's hours in each week and his status and position at that time.

Note:

- Payday is every other Friday; week runs from Saturday through Friday.
- Table tracks when employees status changed.

set dateformat mdy;
declare @EmpHours table
(Employee   int,workday date,payday date,hours  int,position varchar(50));
insert into @EmpHours values
(101,'1/1/2014','1/3/2014',8,'assistant'),
(101,'1/3/2014','1/3/2014',8,'assistant'),
(101,'1/4/2014','1/17/2014',8,'assistant'),
(101,'1/5/2014','1/17/2014',8,'assistant'),
(101,'1/7/2014','1/17/2014',8,'assistant'),
(101,'1/8/2014','1/17/2014',8,'assistant'),
(101,'1/9/2014','1/17/2014',8,'assistant'),
(101,'1/11/2014','1/17/2014',8,'assistant'),
(101,'1/13/2014','1/17/2014',8,'assistant'),
(101,'1/14/2014','1/17/2014',8,'assistant'),
(101,'1/18/2014','2/14/2014',8,'assistant'),
(102,'1/1/2014','1/3/2014',7,'manager'),
(102,'1/25/2014','1/31/2014',7,'manager'),
(102,'1/26/2014','1/31/2014',7,'manager'),
(102,'1/28/2014','1/31/2014',7,'manager'),
(102,'1/31/2014','1/31/2014',7,'manager'),
(103,'1/1/2014','1/3/2014',5,'intern'),
(103,'1/31/2014','1/31/2014',6,'intern'),
(104,'1/14/2014','1/17/2014',5,'supervisor'),
(104,'1/30/2014','1/31/2014',6,'supervisor');

--select * from @EmpHours
declare @EmpStatus table
(employee   int,start_date  date,status varchar(20));
insert into @EmpStatus values
(101,'1/1/2014','parttime'),
(101,'1/18/2014','fulltime'),
(102,'1/1/2014','seasonal'),
(102,'1/18/2014','fulltime'),
(103,'1/1/2014','partime'),
(103,'1/18/2014','fulltime'),
(104,'1/4/2014','parttime'),
(104,'1/18/2014','fulltime');

Table 3

```
employee    status  hours   position    workday weekend payday  
101 parttime    8   assistant   1/1/2014    1/3/2014    1/3/2014    
101 parttime    8   assistant   1/3/2014    1/3/2014    1/3/2014    
101 parttime    8   assistant   1/4/2014    1/10/2014   1/17/2014   
101 parttime    8   assistant   1/5/2014    1/10/2014   1/17/2014   
101 parttime    8   assistant   1/7/2014    1/10/2014   1/17/2014   
101 parttime    8   assistant   1/8/2014    1/10/2014   1/17/2014   
101 parttime    8   assistant   1/9/2014    1/10/2014   1/17/2014   
101 parttime    8   assistant   1/11/2014   1/17/2014   1/17/2014   
101 parttime    8   assistant   1/13/2014   1/17/2014   1/17/2014   
101 parttime    8   assistant   1/14/2014   1/17/2014   1/17/2014   
101 fulltime    8   assistant   1/18/2014   1/24/2014   2/14/2014   
102 seasonal    7   manager 1/1/2014    1/3/2014    1/3/2014    
102 fulltime    7   manager 1/25/2014   1/25/2014   2/14/2014   
102 fulltime    7   manager 1/26/2014   1/26/2014   2/14/2014   
102 fulltime    7   manager 1/28/2014   1/28/2014   2/14/2014   
102 fulltime    7   manager 1/31/2014   1/31/2014   2/14/2014   
103 parttime    5   intern  1/1/2014    1/3/2014    1/3/2014    
103 fulltime    6   intern  1/31/2014   1/31/2014   2/14/2014   
104 parttime    5   supervisor  1/14/2014   1/17/2014   1/17/2014   
104 fulltime    6   supervisor  1/30/2014   1/31/2014   1/31/2014
```

Comment: What RDBMS is it anyway ??? sql server or Mysql or ???

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    EH.Employee
    ,ES.[Status]
    ,SUM(EH.[Hours]) AS Total_Hours
    ,EH.Position
    ,EH.Workday
    ,DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, EH.Workday)), EH.Workday) AS [WeekEnd]
    ,EH.PayDay

FROM    EmpHours EH INNER JOIN EmpStatus ES
ON      EH.Employee = ES.Employee
GROUP BY EH.Employee,ES.[Status],EH.Position,EH.Workday,EH.PayDay
         ,DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, EH.Workday)), EH.Workday)
```